# Why are my comments modified and my user -contacting with "@user:" are removed?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Some users are pointing me that they cannot get my msgs because I do not use the "@" sign. But let me know you that I use "@" sign but SE removes it with everything succeeding it until space. So how can I write comments such as "@mike: I meant the XYZ thing, not the other thing."

I noticed that this activity started to work a short time ago. I cannot understand why my account experience this kind of silencing operation. Why are my comments processed? Why does SE removes "@" sign and everything until a space in commenting?

Have you created some sort of prison mode or what is happening? I am using Google Chrome. I hope this is some sort of technical issue in my browser or something like that. I find comment processing a bit too much.

**[Examples]**

1. If I comment with "@hello: great!", the word "@hello:" is removed.
2. If I comment with "hello: @hello: great!", nothing is removed.

so now instead of using just "@hello", I am now using the form "hello: @hello:" to notify user. I know this is clutter but I cannot understand why my comments are manipulated at the first hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**All comments on a post *always* notify the post owner, always, in every case, forever and ever, amen**. So when only two people are talking, the post owner and another user, we strip `@postowner` out as noise.

Click on the **help link** under the Add Comment button for details:

> Comments use mini-Markdown formatting: `` [link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `code` ``. The post author will always be notified of your comment. To also notify a previous commenter, mention their user name: `@peter` or `@PeterSmith` will both work. [Learn more…](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)